# Using Openpyxl to compare data values in two Excel files when one isn't ordered

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am comparing the income values in two different excel files to evaluate if their is a discrepancy the income for each employee between the files. My issue is that the names in the second file are alphabetized but in the first file they are ordered randomly.

I am very new to python, what search function can I use that creates a list telling me what the corresponding row values in the unordered list are to the alphabetized list.

Here is my code so far.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Gehaltabrechnung_v02.xlsx')
sheet= wb['Tabelle1']
wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('BonusCalculation.xlsx')
sheet2= wb2['Tabelle1']
//imports files and names the workbooks

column_income1 = sheet['G']
income1_length = len(column_income1)
column_name1 = sheet['B']
name1_length = len(column_name1)
column_income2 = sheet2['I']
income2_length = len(column_income2)
column_name2 = sheet2['B']
name2_length = len(column_name2)
//specifies columns and their lengths for the two sheets
```

Comment: Can you post an sample of your Excel file? See [mcve]

Comment: Relevant [check if value from source.xlsx exists in a target.xlsx file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53729626/7414759)